# ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I am trying to build a SQL statement for querying a Oracle database and have two parameters as date types.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(":pCommencementDate", OracleDbType.Date)).Value = comm.OraFormatDate(txtCommenceDate.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(":pCompletionDate", OracleDbType.Date)).Value = comm.OraFormatDate(txtCompleteDate.Text)

Public Function OraFormatDate(ByVal strDate As String) As String
    Try
        Dim a As Date
        SetGlobalDay()
        a = Format(CDate(strDate), "dd/MM/yyyy")
        Return "to_date('" & a & "','dd/mm/yyyy')"
    Catch ex As Exception
        ERR.sWriteErrorLog("C:\", "(common OraFormatDate) -> " & ex.Message)
    End Try

End Function
```

After the query is built, and tried to execute i get the ORA-01858 error.

Comment: Why do you pass a **string** to `OracleParameter`? Set a `Date` value directly. There is no reason to convert the date value first to a string and then convert back again to a date with `TO_DATE()`.

Comment: Post your PL/Sql Stored Procedure, that's where the error is.  @Wernfried Domscheit is correct, just post the date as a string and handle it in the PL/Sql.  No need to convert it like you're doing.

Comment: Thanks guys, Let me try this out and update